# C# how to get each time a method is used in an assembly

Tags: c#

Say that I'm making a plugin that will check each other assembly currently in use for a method. How exactly would I go about doing this? I've tried a bit with the whole `System.Reflection.MethodInfo` but I do not believe this is what I'm looking for. I'm fully aware that this may not even be possible, so let me know if so! Thanks.

**EDIT:** Okay, so specifically I need to get the parameter being passed to the method when it's called

Comment: Can you try rewording your title and/or your question?  I can't quite understand what you are asking.  Are you trying to hook a call (for example, your code would either execute or be notified every time some method (of another class, likely in another assembly) is executed.  You should also show some code in your question.  For example, showing what you want your code to do, and what that "other method" looks like and what it's call site looks like

Comment: I think you need to elaborate further, to get the parameter(s) passed into a method, just place break-point in the method.

Answer (score 1):

[Profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) will give you stats (counts, times, etc) on the various calls your app makes.  There are [many profilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) available. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers) and [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/beginners-guide-to-performance-profiling?view=vs-2017)

I like [dotTrace](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/).  Its not free but it has a 10-day trial.

Comment: While this is an excellent answer, I have since realized my question is rather vague, and edited it to better represent what I'm looking for